# EF Code First NotMapped Attribute?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have properties on my POCOs like the following that allow me to easily access identifying criteria that a user will be able to associate an entity record with for use in my auditing and validation code...

Sometime the Identifer is a simple concatenation of 2 or more scalar fields, and sometimes it has code in it to retrieve and concatenate properties on a Navigation Reference.

I don't need to store this data with each entity in the DB, BUT I do want to be able to access it thru the DbEntityEntry, I tried decorating it with [NotMapped] but then it is not accessible on my entity ?

```
    [Identifer]
    public string Identifer 
    {
        get { return HRContact.Identifer; }
        set { }
    }
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this ?

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean be accessing those data through `DbEntityEntry`. `DbEntityEntry` contains reference to entity in `Entity` property - there you will get access to any properties the entity provides. `DbEntityEntry` also holds collection of current values and original values. These collections will always contain only mapped (persisted) properties because EF never deals with not mapped properties.

Comment: I say DbEntityEntry because I want to use this Identifer property as a read only getter during SaveChanges() as a way to identify a specific record in an entity in a meaningful way for the user instead of primary key etc...  I will use this in both auditing and validation code... I was hoping that EF would allow read only getters and simply ignore them WHEN it came time to generate the SQL to update the DB...

Comment: You have this information in `entry.Entity.Identifier`. You don't need it directly in entry.

Comment: It is not available when I decorate the property with [NotMapped] on the Entry.Entity object... Correct ?

Comment: `Entry.Entity` is just a reference to your entity instance which has everything your class defines including computed properties like your `Identitier`. Man, why don't you try it?